# Clustering in Node vs Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, cluster-computing, hardware

I want to scale out my Node application with clustering.

I have a Node application that is containerized in Docker. In Node, I can [fork child processes](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) to parallelize the application at the thread level, or I can create parallel containers with Kubernetes or Docker Swarm.

What are the tradeoffs here?

This is an encryption server that will accept a file upload, encrypt it, and send it on its way.

Comment: Have you used Express aswell?

Comment: Depends on how many cores you have in the system and the cores allocated to your container. Forking in the child process seems like the easier way, less overhead (require less RAM..etc) to process stuff. Parallel containers with k8..etc provides you with management dashboard ..etc. But require more resources to operate and can be slower in processing as new containers need to be spin up to do parallel processing compare to forking.

Comment: @ThanveerShah yup. Express is used in this application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I found this picture in https://sites.google.com/site/mytechnicalcollection/cloud-computing/docker/container-vs-process . The author has some more comments on this subject. VMs vs Containers vs Processes.

I try to summarize

A. containers advantages:

1. swarm/kubernetes is an excellent scheduler. To run in multi hosts or anywhere within docker.
2. security and limitations. container has many features which is similar to a VM. But it is faster and simpler than VM in many aspects.

B. process fork advantages:

1. lighter than container.

Last but not the least, **you can run fork processes inside a container**. 
You can run only one container per host, and the process inside the container forks depends on the number of its host cores. That would be perfect for you.